# RMI program to preform GC on another JVM

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jvm

i am interested to write a java program to perform GC on another JVm which present in the another machine. Presently i am monitoring the JVM manually means i am opening jconsole in my machine & preform GC when the JVM memory croses particular memory limit. i want to do automatically by java program..

please provide suggestions....

Thanks,
Krishna

Comment: Just don't. Leave garbage collection to garbage collector. You cannot help doing GC manually - you can only interfere.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a terrible hack to deal with a problem almost certainly unrelated to the garbage collector itself.  Forcing full garbage collection is almost never what you want to do.  There's multiple threads on stackoverflow about it, such as [Why is it a bad practice to call System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc)

The short answer is, don't do that.  Tune your GC options to make it do what you want instead.

If you have evaluated all other options and *still* want to go down this path of sadness, you could just have an RMI method invoke `System.gc()` as Mr. Flamer suggests.  If you **really really** want to be sure, use the [JVMTI ForceGarbageCollection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#memory) method.

Answer (score 0):

But remember when you call System.gc() it is not guaranteed to start garbagecollection. You should leave this to the JVM.