# Tomcat Guice/JDBC Memory Leak

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm experiencing a memory leak due to orphaned threads in Tomcat. Particularly, it seems that Guice and the JDBC driver are not closing threads.

```
Aug 8, 2012 4:09:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Aug 8, 2012 4:09:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I know this is similar to other questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025089/guice-tomcat-potential-memory-leak)), but in my case, the answer of "don't worry about it" won't be sufficient, as it is causing problems for me. I have CI server which regularly updates this application, and after 6-10 reloads, the CI server will hang because Tomcat is out of memory.

I need to be able to clear up these orphaned threads so I can run my CI server more reliably. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sure these are the cause of OOM error? The JDBC issue solves by killing the thread using a context listener on context destroy event AND putting the driver in app's lib so the classloading is done in app's context, not in container's.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to this space, so I'm not at all sure this is the cause of the OOM error, but it's the only suspicious note I'm getting in Tomcat's log when I redeploy this web app. Any tips on finding the source or properly using the contextListener as you recommend? I didn't spot any obviously relevant tutorials after a quick Google, but I'd be happy to read up on the issue if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: To unload drivers using a contextlistener, look at the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Tomcat shows the thread "Abandoned connection cleanup thread" for as many times as the webapp was restarted and de-registering the drivers is not helping me at all... any good news?

Comment: Maybe it's me not very smart, but I don't see an answer related also to the guava problem (most of answers focus on mysql conn pool), that affects me (before adding that thing the app was cleaning up well on reload/stop): I end up setting a higher limit for the perm gen space, so I can wait more time among tomcat restarts because of this. Pretty sad to see a Google library sith a memory leak...

Comment: I am using MySql driver 5.1.36 and i am seeing the error.  Is this bug ever got fixed?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I just dealt with this problem myself.  Contrary to some other answers, I do not recommend issuing the `t.stop()` command.  This method has been deprecated, and for good reason. Reference [Oracle's reasons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for doing this.

However there is a solution for removing this error without needing to resort to `t.stop()`...

You can use most of the code @Oso provided, just replace the following section

```
Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
for(Thread t:threadArray) {
    if(t.getName().contains("Abandoned connection cleanup thread")) {
        synchronized(t) {
            t.stop(); //don't complain, it works
        }
    }
}
```

Replace it using the following method provided by the MySQL driver:

```
try {
    AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    logger.warn("SEVERE problem cleaning up: " + e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should properly shutdown the thread, and the error should go away.

Comment: This was initially a pain to find.  No javadocs, little reference.  I discovered it looking through bug reports on tomcat.  Here is an indirect reference from oracle itself.   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-relnotes-en/news-5-1-23.html

Comment: Ah awesome, I was on 5.1.22. The class was introduced in 5.1.23. +1 Thanks

Comment: (sorry comments do not format this well...) The link you had on "Oracle's reasons" should be updated to:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

I would add a suggestion on where to place this.

Using spring I have this in my web.xml
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.mypackage.web.context.MyContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

That class extends org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

and on contextDestroyed() I do that.

Comment: `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown();` is deprecated. It is suggested to use `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkedShutdown()`.

Comment: As of 2018-07-25, AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkedShutdown() is also deprecated. I am unable to find any documentation on this class.

Comment: The Connector/J developers do not seem to understand how to build a driver that can be used in this kind of context. https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=73876 and https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69526

Comment: There is a problem with blindly calling `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.((un)checked)shutdown`: if the driver is being shared among multiple applications, the thread will be terminated *for all applications* and the thread cannot be restarted. You might want to check the loading ClassLoader for `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread` before shutting it down in a context-finalizer.

Answer (score 15):

I've had the same issue, and as Jeff says, the "don't worry about it approach" was not the way to go.

I did a ServletContextListener that stops the hung thread when the context is being closed, and then registered such ContextListener on the web.xml file.

I already know that stopping a thread is not an elegant way to deal with them, but otherwise the server keeps on crashing after two or three deploys (it is not always possible to restart the app server).

The class I created is:

```
public class ContextFinalizer implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContextFinalizer.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        Driver d = null;
        while(drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                d = drivers.nextElement();
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
                LOGGER.warn(String.format("Driver %s deregistered", d));
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                LOGGER.warn(String.format("Error deregistering driver %s", d), ex);
            }
        }
        Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
        for(Thread t:threadArray) {
            if(t.getName().contains("Abandoned connection cleanup thread")) {
                synchronized(t) {
                    t.stop(); //don't complain, it works
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

After creating the class, then register it on the web.xml file:

```
<web-app...
    <listener>
        <listener-class>path.to.ContextFinalizer</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This is a bad solution for three reasons. 1. It uses t.stop(), which is not only deprecated, but scheduled for removal. 2. It depends on an arbitrary program string which could change ("Abandoned connection cleanup thread"). 3. It synchronizes on a `Thread` object which could result in surprising deadlocks.

Answer (score 14):

The least invasive workaround is to force initialisation of the MySQL JDBC driver from code outside of the webapp's classloader.

In tomcat/conf/server.xml, modify (inside the Server element):

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
```

to

```
<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"
          classesToInitialize="com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver" />
```

- *With mysql-connector-java-8.0.x use `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver` instead*

This assumes you put the MySQL JDBC driver into tomcat's lib directory and not inside your webapp.war's WEB-INF/lib directory, as the whole point is to load the driver *before* and independently of your webapp.

References:

- http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68556#c400606
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JRE_Memory_Leak_Prevention_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener
- http://markmail.org/message/dmvlkps7lbgpngil
- [com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java) source v5.1
- [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/NonRegisteringDriver.java) source v8.0
- [Changes in connector/J v8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html)

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. I am using TomEE 1.6.0 (Tomcat 7.0.47) and MySQL driver 5.1.27. Finally I have choosed the solution based on the AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread class. The Thread killing is also worked for me but I prefer the solution which is directly connected to the source of the problem which is the MySQL JDBC driver itself.

Comment: @MiklosKrivan you did put your JDBC driver .jar file in tomcat's lib directory and not inside your .war's WEB-INF/lib, right? I believe the first approach is required for the JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener to work, and assume the latter approach is required to ever re-start the AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread thread after being shut down once (it's started from a static initializer in the JDBC driver itself).

Comment: Yes I always put the JDBC driver into the Tomcat's lib because I use datasources and I prefer if the container manages the database pool and not the application. This is required in enterprise java app servers as well what I am using usally. Your suggestion was related to the situation where JDBC driver is in the Tomcat's lib. That is why I have written my comment. Maybe I have misunderstood something?

Comment: @MiklosKrivan won't putting the JDBC driver in Tomcat's lib directory and then calling AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown() cause that thread to stop running forever until tomcat is restarted, stopping the cleanup of connections it would otherwise do in the background for other or redeployed webapps? If your webapps are well-behaving and always close their connections properly that might not matter though of course, haven't looked into the details of what AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread actually does.

Answer (score 11):

Effective from MySQL connector 5.1.23 onwards, a method is provided to shut the abandoned connection cleanup thread down, `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown`.

However, we don't want direct dependencies in our code on the otherwise opaque JDBC driver code, so my solution is to use reflection to find the class and method and invoke it if found.  The following complete code snippet is all that's needed, executed in the context of the class loader that loaded the JDBC driver:

```
try {
    Class<?> cls=Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread");
    Method   mth=(cls==null ? null : cls.getMethod("shutdown"));
    if(mth!=null) { mth.invoke(null); }
    }
catch (Throwable thr) {
    thr.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This cleanly ends the thread if the JDBC driver is a sufficiently recent version of the MySQL connector and otherwise does nothing.

Note it has to be executed in the context of the class loader because the thread is a static reference; if the driver class is not being or has not already been unloaded when this code is run then the thread will not be running for subsequent JDBC interactions.

Comment: I find this to be the best answer of all for two reasons 1) It doesn't use Thread.stop() and 2) It doesn't require an explicit app dependency on the MySQL connector.

Answer (score 6):

I took the best parts of the answers above and combined them into an easily extensible class.  This combines Oso's original suggestion with Bill's driver improvement and Software Monkey's reflection improvement.  (I liked the simplicity of Stephan L's answer too, but sometimes modifying the Tomcat environment itself is not a good option, especially if you have to deal with autoscaling or migration to another web container.)

Instead of directly referring to the class name, thread name, and stop method, I also encapsulated these into an private inner ThreadInfo class.  Using a list of these ThreadInfo objects, you can include additional troublesome threads to be shutdown with the same code.  This is a bit more complex of a solution than most people likely need, but should work more generally when you need that.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


/**
 * Context finalization to close threads (MySQL memory leak prevention).
 * This solution combines the best techniques described in the linked Stack
 * Overflow answer.
 * @see <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872316/tomcat-guice-jdbc-memory-leak">Tomcat Guice/JDBC Memory Leak</a>
 */
public class ContextFinalizer
    implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER =
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContextFinalizer.class);

    /**
     * Information for cleaning up a thread.
     */
    private class ThreadInfo {

        /**
         * Name of the thread's initiating class.
         */
        private final String name;

        /**
         * Cue identifying the thread.
         */
        private final String cue;

        /**
         * Name of the method to stop the thread.
         */
        private final String stop;

        /**
         * Basic constructor.
         * @param n Name of the thread's initiating class.
         * @param c Cue identifying the thread.
         * @param s Name of the method to stop the thread.
         */
        ThreadInfo(final String n, final String c, final String s) {
            this.name = n;
            this.cue  = c;
            this.stop = s;
        }

        /**
         * @return the name
         */
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        /**
         * @return the cue
         */
        public String getCue() {
            return this.cue;
        }

        /**
         * @return the stop
         */
        public String getStop() {
            return this.stop;
        }
    }

    /**
     * List of information on threads required to stop.  This list may be
     * expanded as necessary.
     */
    private List<ThreadInfo> threads = Arrays.asList(
        // Special cleanup for MySQL JDBC Connector.
        new ThreadInfo(
            "com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "Abandoned connection cleanup thread", //$NON-NLS-1$
            "shutdown" //$NON-NLS-1$
        )
    );

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // No-op.
    }

    @Override
    public final void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent sce) {

        // Deregister all drivers.
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
            Driver d = drivers.nextElement();
            try {
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
                LOGGER.info(
                    String.format(
                        "Driver %s deregistered", //$NON-NLS-1$
                        d
                    )
                );
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.warn(
                    String.format(
                        "Failed to deregister driver %s", //$NON-NLS-1$
                        d
                    ),
                    e
                );
            }
        }

        // Handle remaining threads.
        Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
        Thread[] threadArray = threadSet.toArray(new Thread[threadSet.size()]);
        for (Thread t:threadArray) {
            for (ThreadInfo i:this.threads) {
                if (t.getName().contains(i.getCue())) {
                    synchronized (t) {
                        try {
                            Class<?> cls = Class.forName(i.getName());
                            if (cls != null) {
                                Method mth = cls.getMethod(i.getStop());
                                if (mth != null) {
                                    mth.invoke(null);
                                    LOGGER.info(
                                        String.format(
            "Connection cleanup thread %s shutdown successfully.", //$NON-NLS-1$
                                            i.getName()
                                        )
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Throwable thr) {
                            LOGGER.warn(
                                    String.format(
            "Failed to shutdown connection cleanup thread %s: ", //$NON-NLS-1$
                                        i.getName(),
                                        thr.getMessage()
                                    )
                                );
                            thr.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I went a step further from Oso,improved the code above in two points:

1. Added the Finalizer thread to the need-to-kill check:

   ```
   for(Thread t:threadArray) {
           if(t.getName().contains("Abandoned connection cleanup thread") 
               ||  t.getName().matches("com\\.google.*Finalizer")
               ) {
           synchronized(t) {
               logger.warn("Forcibly stopping thread to avoid memory leak: " + t.getName());
               t.stop(); //don't complain, it works
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Sleep for a little while to give threads time to stop. Without that, tomcat kept complaining.

   ```
   try {
       Thread.sleep(1000);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       logger.debug(e.getMessage(), e);
   }
   ```

Comment: It's a bad idea to make code dependent on an arbitrary string which could change in the future without warning ("Abandoned connection cleanup thread").

Comment: "*it's better than having your server leaking*" : Until the text changes at some possibly distant future time, and your server starts leaking again, and the first time you realize it when it crashes.

Comment: Feel free to suggest a better way.. Don't get me wrong, I hate workarounds, but they are better than than the problems they patch if you don't have a more elegant solution.

Comment: I do, and it's [already posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17892862/8946), back in July 2013.

Comment: Your answer fixes the mysql leak, it's better than mine in this regard, but what about Google's?

Comment: Your answer may be the only possible one for Google's thread (I missed that in the question way back when). So, if it were me, I'd use my solution for the JDBC driver thread, and research further on the Google thread, possibly resorting to your answer if there were absolutely no other better way. So on that, we agree, a crude, brittle solution is better than no solution. Of course, as I said, `Thread.stop()` is slated for removal in Java10 (IIRC), so it has a limited lifespan.

Answer (score 2):

Bill's solution looks good, however I found another solution directly in MySQL bug reports:

> [5 Jun 2013 17:12] Christopher Schultz
>   Here is a much better workaround until something else changes.
>
> Enable Tomcat's JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener (enabled by default on Tomcat 7), and add this attribute to the  element:
>
> **classesToInitialize="com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver"**
>
> If "classesToInitialize" is already set on your , just add NonRegisteringDriver to the existing value separated by a comma.

and the answer:

> [8 Jun 2013 21:33] Marko Asplund
>   I did some testing with the  JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener / classesToInitialize workaround (Tomcat 7.0.39 + MySQL Connector/J 5.1.25).
>
> Before applying the workaround thread dumps listed multiple AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread instances after redeploying the webapp several times. After applying the workaround there's only one AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread instance.
>
> **I had to modify my app, though, and move MySQL driver from the webapp to Tomcat lib.**
>   Otherwise, the classloader is unable to load com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver at Tomcat startup.

I hope it helps for all who still fighting with this issue...

Answer (score 2):

It seems this was fixed in **5.1.41**. You could upgrade Connector/J to 5.1.41 or newer. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-41.html

> The implementation of AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread has now been improved, so that there are now four ways for developers to deal with the situation:
>
> - When the default Tomcat configuration is used and the Connector/J jar is put into a local library directory, the new built-in application detector in Connector/J now detects the stopping of the web application within 5 seconds and kills AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread. Any unnecessary warnings about the thread being unstoppable are also avoided. If the Connector/J jar is put into a global library directory, the thread is left running until the JVM is unloaded.
> - When Tomcat's context is configured with the attribute clearReferencesStopThreads="true", Tomcat is going to stop all spawned threads when the application stops unless Connector/J is being shared with other web applications, in which case Connector/J is now protected against an inappropriate stop by Tomcat; the warning about the non-stoppable thread is still issued into Tomcat's error log.
> - When a ServletContextListener is implemented within each web application that calls AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkedShutdown() on context destruction, Connector/J now, again, skips this operation if the driver is potentially shared with other applications. No warning about the thread being unstoppable is issued to Tomcat's error log in this case.
> - When AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.uncheckedShutdown() is called, the AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread is closed even if Connector/J is shared with other applications. However, it may not be possible to restart the thread afterwards.

If you look at source code, they called setDeamon(true) on thread, so it won't block shutdown.

```
Thread t = new Thread(r, "Abandoned connection cleanup thread");
t.setDaemon(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

See [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered/23912257#23912257). Bill's answer deregisters all Driver instances as well as instances that may belong to other web applications.  I have extended Bill's answer with a check that the Driver instance belongs to the right `ClassLoader`.

Here is the resulting code (in a separate method, because my `contextDestroyed` has other things to do):

```
// See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699985/the-web-application-appears-to-have-started-a-thread-named-abandoned-connect
// and
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered/23912257#23912257
private void avoidGarbageCollectionWarning()
{
    ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    Driver d = null;
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
        try {
            d = drivers.nextElement();
            if(d.getClass().getClassLoader() == cl) {
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(d);
                logger.info(String.format("Driver %s deregistered", d));
            }
            else {
                logger.info(String.format("Driver %s not deregistered because it might be in use elsewhere", d.toString()));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException ex) {
            logger.warning(String.format("Error deregistering driver %s, exception: %s", d.toString(), ex.toString()));
        }
    }
    try {
         AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.warning("SEVERE problem cleaning up: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I wonder whether the call `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown()` is safe. Can it interfere with other web applications? I hope not, because the `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run()` method is not static but the `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown()` method is.