# Application doesn't start up with tomcat 8 due to memory leak

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, memory-leaks

In my application I have used apache-tomcat-8.0.18 and java 1.8. I receive the following error at Tomcat start up:

```
05-May-2015 20:59:18.812 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/MyApplication] startup failed due to previous errors
05-May-2015 20:59:18.829 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [MyApplication] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.

05-May-2015 20:59:18.830 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [MyApplication] appears to have started a thread named          [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
                            java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)          
                            java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)          
                            java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)     
                            java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dilan.common</groupId>
<artifactId>Struts2Example</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>com.dilan.common</version>
<name>Struts2Example Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-sitemesh-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
        <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring related dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-struts</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jasper related dependencies-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--////////////////////////////////////////-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.23</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jasperreports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.20</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-attrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.Beta1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.ga</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ognl</groupId>
        <artifactId>ognl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.web.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.web.portlet</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<build>
    <finalName>MyApplication</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The thread leak (different than a memory leak) isn't the problem.  Note the first line of the log you posted:  `startup failed due to previous errors`.  There's something else causing your app to fail.  The thing about the timer thread is just shutdown "noise" (i.e. the app has failed to start and tomcat is shutting down).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17892862/185565 try this code in contextlistener.contextdestroyed