# Memory leak in MySql JDBC AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread

Tags: java, spring-boot, memory-leaks, spring-jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm using springBoot Java application with MySql connector latest version: **8.0.26** ('mysql-connector-java').

More specifically it's happening in `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.connectionFinalizerPhantomRefs` object.

I tried multiple approaches which is already mentioned in some forums ([stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872316/tomcat-guice-jdbc-memory-leak), mySql community etc) like manually cleaning up the `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread` thread but nothing works at all.

Below is my implementation, mentioned in [this link](https://www.ralph-schuster.eu/2014/07/09/solution-to-tomcat-cant-stop-an-abandoned-connection-cleanup-thread/):

```
public static void closeAbandonedConnectionCleanupThread() {
    try {
        AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkedShutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception while cleaning up MySql thread: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Below is the heap-dump analysis for reference,

[image]

**Any help would be appreciated.**