# OpenAM13.0.0--Tomcat Shutdown Automatically

Tags: java, tomcat, openam

We have deployed openam13.0.0 war in Tomcat8.026 version server.  If server is idle for 12 to 24 hours, it gets stopped automatically and throws the below error.  Please provide your suggestions on this.

> org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads
>   The web application [openam] appears to have started a thread named
>   [com.google.inject.internal.util.$Finalizer] but has failed to stop
>   it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of
>   thread:  java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)

Comment: That seems more like a warning than an error

Comment: The cause cannot be specified from the above error. Please check if there are any messages which seem to be related to this problem in OpenAM debug logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to Tomcat: 
[Guice + Tomcat potential memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025089/guice-tomcat-potential-memory-leak)

and more than likely this bug:
https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-3133

The issue you are seeing is happening only when Tomcat is stopping. As long as Tomcat isn't actually prevented from shutting down then these are fairly harmless.

As reported in the bug report, this issue has been there since OpenAM 10 with recent version of Tomcats, it is fair to assume that the errors can be safety ignored as long as the Tomcat is able to shutdown. The discussion in the bug report OpenAM-3133 give a fairly good assessment of the situation.

Cheers