# Does Parallel GC support shrinking heap size?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvisualvm

I got two conflicting answers regarding this question from two places.

1. The [baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/gc-release-memory) says

> For example, **Parallel GC doesn’t release unused memory** back to the OS readily.

So I think Parallel GC **will not shrink** the heap size.

2. The [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os) says

> you can make the GC more aggressive in general by setting -XX:GCTimeRatio=19 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30 which will allow it to spend more CPU time on **collecting and constrain the amount of allocated-but-unused heap memory** after a GC cycle.

So I think I can **force the garbage collector to shrink** the heap size.

3. Based on the above understanding, I do experiments on my machine.

   3.1 The jdk:

   > java version "1.8.0_271" 
   > Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
   > Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)

   3.2 I use `jmap -heap` command to print the GC information, the output is as below

   > .....(omit other infomration)
   > using thread-local object allocation. 
   > **Parallel GC** with 8 thread(s)

   3.3 I run an application with VM options `-Xmx10240m`(it is the only heap-related VM option I set manually), and open `jvisualvm` to observe the change of heap size. I notice the heap size(the orange part) shrinks when the used heap size(the blue part) becomes smaller. It violates the first article.
   [image]

   3.4 I run the same application with VM options `-Xmx10240m -XX: MaxHeapFreeRatio=100`, I set the option `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=100` in order to tell GC not to shrink. But it does not work either.
   [image]
4. My concrete question is:

   4.1 The [baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/gc-release-memory) says Parallel GC doesn’t release unused memory, so why does the heap size in Figure 1 still shrink?

   4.2 The [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os) says the -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio will make some differences, but it didn't.

Any help will be appraciated.

Answer (score 1):

In [this bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6498735) about releasing memory, there is a [ten year old comment](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-6498735#comment-13388231) from Jesper Wilhelmsson:

> I have verified that G1 (-XX:+UseG1GC), Parallel scavenge (-XX:+UseParallelGC) and ParallelOld (-XX:+UseParallelOldGC) do return memory when the heap shrinks. I'm not so sure about Serial and CMS, they didn't shrink their heap in my experiments.
>
> Both parallel collectors do require a number of GCs before shrinking the heap down to an "acceptable" size. This is per design. They are deliberately holding on to the heap assuming that it will be needed in the future. Setting the flag -XX:GCTimeRatio=1 will improve the situation somewhat but it will still take several GCs to shrink a lot.

I would trust the JDK developers more than articles on baeldung.com or rather, I’d treat articles on baeldung.com with a grain of salt in general. There is no sign of a quality assurance process on that site and it’s not the first time, incorrect information has been found on that site.

Comment: Thanks. I trust this article at the beginning because it is written by the website author, not the individual author. And I also get the same opinion, like [another so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150668/why-isnt-the-allocated-heap-memory-shrinking-when-usage-is-below-maxheapfreerat) which says `The -XX:ParallelGC switch inhibits heap shrinking`. These things confuse me.

Comment: Before Java 9, the Parallel GC did not respect the `-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio`/ `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` settings. Whatever heuristic it is using in the older versions, its result is to release only tiny amounts, if any. I did a lot of tests with different settings and it did release tiny amounts in some configurations but nothing in others. I could not derive a rule from these results. But it showed that 1) Parallel GC has support for releasing memory even in older versions but 2) it’s not surprising that people think it hadn’t if they made some tests with little variance in the configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you misread the baeldung article.

The article [Does GC Release Back Memory to OS?](https://www.baeldung.com/gc-release-memory#garbage-collectors) writes

> For example, Parallel GC doesn’t release unused memory back to the OS readily.

You marked the first part but missed the last word: **readily**. That sentence is

> For example, **Parallel GC doesn’t release unused memory** [..] **readily.**

i.e. it can release memory back to the OS, but it is reluctant to do so (probably because releasing memory back to the OS just to allocate new memory from the OS is expensive).

---

> The [so thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os) says the -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio will make some differences, but it didn't.

Yes it says so. And it writes that you can make the GC more aggresive by setting (among others) `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30`.

The point is: the default value for MaxHeapFreeRatio is 70. If setting it to 30 makes it more aggressive, then setting it to 100 makes it less aggressive.

You can actually see in [`PSAdaptiveSizePolicy::calculated_old_free_size_in_bytes()`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/blob/jdk8u272-ga/hotspot/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge/psAdaptiveSizePolicy.cpp#L97) that setting the MaxHeapFreeRation to 100 effectively disables it.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you on the first question about the baeldung article. For the second question, as Figure 2 shows, I have already set up `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=100` but it still shrinks(I tried it again just now, and the same thing happens). You said that `setting it to 100 makes it less aggressive`, so even though I set up `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=100`,  it still be possible for GC to shrink and the JVM option is just a hint?

Comment: @Jinke2017 the MaxHeapFreeRatio sets an upper bound on the (old gen) heap size - i.e. when growing the old gen heap it should never do it to a size so high that more than MaxHeapFreeRatio is free. As there can never be more than 100% heap free this means there is no upper bound (beyound what you set with -Xmx). But that setting doesn't imply that the JVM may not shrink the heap size. (For me it is not entirely clear how this apply to the young generation)

Comment: I read the [java command doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABHDABI), and it doesn't mention `MaxHeapFreeRatio` only applies on old generation. How do you get this information?

Comment: I didn't claim that `MaxHeapFreeRatio` doesn't apply to the young generation. I wrote that _for me it is not entirely clear how this applies to the young generation_. And I wrote that because in my research into the source code (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk8u/tree/jdk8u272-ga/hotspot/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/parallelScavenge) I didn't find how it influences the young generation and I'm too lazy to dig further into the sources.