# What is the correct way to load a bitmap to an imageView

Tags: android, bitmap

In my application I have a list of ImageViews. The size of these ImageViews is 1024x512. In xml this is how each ImageView is defined:

```
<ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="75dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/pic" />
```

and this is how I set each ImageView's bitmap in the getView in ArrayAdapter:

```
        File picToLoad = new File(localPhotosUrl.get(0));
        byte[] array= null;
        try {
            array= org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(picToLoad);

            System.gc();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
            holder.imgIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
       }
```

Now notice that the Image that I'm loading from the sd card is 1024x512 but the ImageView is 75x75. Is this way correct? meaning setting image Bitmap the whole picture or is it memory consuming? should I resize the Image to 75x75 before calling setImageBitmap or it won't make any changes?

Comment: Read below for answer, but also you shouldn't be calling `System.gc()` , it's a bad practice (except for very-very particular cases), android handles garbage collection for you

Comment: why is it bad practice? if anything it collects some garbage early.I also think that calling GC explicitly doesn't ensure that the garbage will be collected

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc) and [this](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6668279)

Comment: The second link wouldn't open but I read the first.Thx for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [Loading Large  Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)  article on official android page. It's very helpful with loading Bitmaps

Comment: I would actually say go one level up in the documentation - http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Ok, excuse me for my mistake, it won't happen again :)