# Tenured Generation Garbage Collection

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

How does the **Tenured Generation** get cleaned by the JVM garbage collector?
Until the allocated heap size is full or?

Because for my project, I have a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which submits a large amount of tasks.
And since these `runnable tasks` are created by an `inner class`, they have certain reference to the outer instance. They will easily survive the `GC` in the `Eden Space` and finally get passed to `Tenured Generation` form `Survivor Space`. And, by monitoring the JVM by Java Profiler, I notice that this `Tenured Generation` never get cleared(until full, for my case).

So my questions are:

1. How `Garbage Collector` works for the `Tenured Generation` Heap?
2. If I wanna force the  `GC` of the memory to prevent unpredictable future `Heap`issues, what may I do?

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, and the answer changes depending on which GC algorithm you are using.  You may want to have a play with the G1 collector, it does not have eden and tenured spaces at all.

Comment: A little off topic to your question, but it may help the intent behind the question.  Are you able to break the reference from the inner class, perhaps by using a static class and passing any data that it needs in to its constructor?

Comment: @ChrisK All of the instances of my runnable `inner class` will update some count of the `outer class`. These instance are controlled(or say used) by a `ThreadPoolExecutor`, which is in the outer class instance, which has a large capacity of queue. So, any suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisK And about garbage collector, I didn't learn that much. It's all with default configuration of the JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How Garbage Collector works for the Tenured Generation Heap?

Well, it's pretty much as you described. Nothing happens until space is needed (or might be needed soon), at which point a major GC is triggered. I'd imagine this was intended behavior -- don't want stop-the-world pauses triggering more frequently than they should.

> If I wanna force the  GC of the memory to prevent unpredictable future Heap issues, what may I do?

Technically, you can't. The GC triggers whenever it wants to, regardless of any hints you give it. If you want to *suggest* the runtime perform a GC, you can use `System.gc()`, but again, that's only a suggestion -- the runtime is free to ignore it if it wants. From what I've heard though, a `System.gc()` call tends to be heeded.

Comment: Thank you, is calling System.gc() safe?

Comment: @ROROROOROROR If by "safe" you mean "won't crash the system", I'd assume so, unless you have some wonky finalizers somewhere and/or the GC overhead doesn't trigger an exception/error. In other words, yes, calling `System.gc()` is safe in the majority of cases. Note that it's not necessarily recommended practice, as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc).