# Changing reference of object and garbage collector

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection

So in Java if I have two objects of the same type and I set one of them to the other one(both have the same reference) will the garbage collector be called?

```
ClassName obj1 = new ClassName();
ClassName obj2 = new ClassName();
obj1 = obj2;
```

Will this call garbage collector? The reason I am asking is because I am making a game for android and I can't have the garbage collector being called while the game is running, as I want the best performance. I know that the "new" keyword will call garbage collection but I don't know if this will. Thanks!

Comment: No, the garbage collector is only "called" when measurements in the system indicate it should be.  You don't have to worry about when this is.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor ("new" keyword) doesn't call the garbage collector.
Once you assign `obj2` to `obj1`, if there are no more references to the original object referred by `obj1`, the garbage collector can collect it, but you don't know when that would happen.

Comment: Well I need to know when it will happen so that I make sure it doesn't run during my game.

Answer (score 3):

Simply unreferencing objects does not force the garbage collector to run. It simply means the object is eligible for collection at some point in the future.
There are multiple garbage collection strategies and implementations. Oracle continues to provide new GC strategies through all recent java versions. I am not as familiar with android, but I assume it likely uses even different GC strategies than Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The object that obj1 *was* pointing to will become **eligible** for garbage collection. You cannot control when the garbage collector is called.

Comment: You can trigger the garbage collection: [`System.gc()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#gc--)

Comment: This is recognized as a bad practice and generally discouraged. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-a-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc

Comment: Explicitly calling gc() in Android is (or used to be, a couple of years back) required under certain circumstances, to trigger collection of image objects that do not reside in regular heap.  But that's one of the few cases where calling gc() is useful.

Comment: For game development performance is everything and garbage collector will decrease it significantly. Is there any way to sort of 'restrict' the garbage collector to a certain time frame to ensure it doesn't ruin gameplay?