# JVM garbage collector seems to fail

Tags: java, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

We have a java application that reads a chunk of data but keeps that data only for a short period of time. The data is stored in "simple" collections (`HashMap`, `HashSet`). These collections are cleared when the data is processed (so I call `coll.clear()` and not `coll=null`). The cycle (read-process-clear) continues, until "all chunks of data" are processed. After a certain amount of time, there will be "new chunks" and the whole thing starts again.

This process has run for several weeks on a server without any problem. 
However, today, after a planned restart, it crashed over and over and again with an `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` (and restarted automatically by a monitoring process).

I connected to the process with a remote debugger AND with the *jvisualvm* tool to try and find if (and where) I could have a memory leak. While the processing-thread was paused (by the debugger) right after the calls to `clear()`, I forced a `gc` with the jvisualvm tool. As I had expected, it cleared almost the entire heap (only 4MB used). Next cycles: same behavour, almost no usage of the heap after `clear`, etc... In the end, the process did *not* go out of memory anymore!

**To me, it looks like the garbage collector failed to work correctly...**

- how can I verify if that's the case?
- if so, how can this be?
- should I call `System.gc()` after the `clear()` methods?

  But as far as I know (and read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc)), that would only be a "suggestion" to the VM; ánd the GC will always collect all possible garbage when the heap is almost full; ánd such a call should simply be avoided :-)...

(we're running Java 1.6.0_51-b11 in server mode on Solaris, no special GC-options)

**EDIT** after analyzing heap dumps:

Our code has this structure:

```
final DataCollector collector = ...
while (!collector.isDone()) {
    final List<Data> dataList = collector.collectNext();
    for (final Data data : dataList) {
        // process data...
    }
}
```

The `OOMError` occurs while executing the `collector.collectNext()` method.

It looks like the heap still contains the `dataList` variable (and all Data objects) of the **previous** iteration of the `while` loop!

Is it normal behavour that a local variable of a while loop does not get garbage-collected? If that's true, we have to give this process almost twice as much memory as strictly needed...

As a hack/check, I added a line `dataList = null` after the for-loop, but this does not change the behaviour (still `OOM`, heap dump still shows the same 'double assignment').

(I guess we were lucky that the process did not crash earlier.)

Comment: Post the entire stack trace for the `OutOfMemoryError`; it can have additional messages that are helpful.

Comment: "The entire stacktrace" is impossible: the process had crashed +40 times, each time with a complete different stack trace (except for the 5 calls after `main()`). I.m.o. it is also useless: the exact code where the `OOMError` occurs can be practically anything, here I see it occuring in `java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap`, `com.sybase.jdbc4.utils.BufferPool.makeBuffer`, `java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeFields`, `java.util.jar.Manifest$FastInputStream.<init>`, etc...

Comment: @chrylis: `Java heap space`, if that's what you mean. Updated original question.

Comment: Are you sure nothing has changed? Some Java update or a new version of the application? It's inexplicable, so everything must be considered. As a hack I'd try to give the process more memory and I'd *surely* try `System.gc()` (just remove it later when the problem gets solved).

Comment: @maaartinus: yes, i'm sure :-).

Comment: Sure, the GC can be broken. However, it is way more probable that your own code is broken. Add `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` and analyze the heap dump with Ecilpse MAT.

Comment: @KristofferE: analyzing the heap dump has puzzled me more, see my edited question...

Comment: The next step I think would be to turn on all the verbose garbage collecting info. To me it seems like something is going wrong with the garbage collector since it works if you manually do it, and it's just a matter of figuring that out.

Comment: I just noticed you are on b11? Upgrade that JVM at least to the latest version of Java 6 if not to Java 8. Earlier builds of Java 6 are VERY buggy.

Comment: We'e on java6 v.51 (not 11). But the problem persists in java7 and 8. After analyzing more heap dumps, the objects that we believe should be collected, are all immediate members of the "native stack". Apparently there still are stack pointers to the heap that are not yet reset to `null` but that we know will never be used again. Also, I cannot reproduce my "fix" of manual-force-gc as initially described. I guess I was lucky, and the only option is to increase the heap size -- which we have done.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into issues where the garbage collector bails after a certain amount of time and false OOMEs occur. This tends to happen when you have a complex chain of objects with lots of circles. The solution is to use the `-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit` flag to tell the garbage collector not to give up.

Comment: I disagree twice: 1. GC has no problem with complex chains, especially if unreachable (GC does not really collect garbage, it picks up the non-garbage instead and what's left is free memory). 2. It's not really false OOME, it's a situation when collecting memory takes long and the gain is small. This means that the application will hardly get a chance to run.

Comment: @maaartinus This has been the recommended workaround by Oracle/Sun for various bugs. In particular there was a nasty one with SoftReference objects resulting in things never being garbage collected, but there has been various others. Many of these have been fixed/adjusted in newer JVMs but the OP is clearly using an older JVM in which this may not have been fixed. Once the GC gets past the "complexities" the first time it runs smoothly. It doesn't cause the application to freeze up as you suggest.

Comment: I know about the `SoftReference` bug, but not the others. Every time I saw "GC overhead too high", things got only worse when suppressed. But my experience is limited, so you may be right. However, the OP's getting "Java heap space", which seems to be a different problem.

Comment: @Necreaux: for what I can find about that option, the option would only have an effect if the error msg was `GC overhead limit exceeded`. In my case it's a `java heap space` error, so that wouldn't help... or is this not correct? Also, could you point to the these oracle/sun recommendations, and/or the bugs?

Comment: @Geronimo Yes, the `GC overhead limit exceeded` is it, but I've seen it buried inside the stack trace or chained inside other exceptions. Depending on how your exceptions are being printed, you might not be seeing it. My thought has always been that this option can't hurt. AFAIK worst case scenario, if there is a GENUINE memory leak, this just makes the JVM thrash around a little while before the OOME rather than throwing it immediately. It's also something to try when you don't have any other good ideas.

Comment: Adding this flag does **not** help :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and what I did was :

Clean your project by going to : `Project > Clean > Clean all projects (tick this option)`

And if problem persists you need to refactor your code, and get rid of memory leak.