# Getting Half Images while loading from URL

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I am loading images from URL and showing on the imageview at runtime.

My problem is sometimes my images are shown only HALF OF THE IMAGE and rest part of the image is shown white. Have read many posts on the net but none of them has helped me in the same..

Kindly provide a good solution for the same and the real cause.

Here is the code I have used to create the bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromCard(String path, int reqWidth,
            int reqHeight) {
        try {
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                    reqHeight);
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            System.gc();
            System.gc();
            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            options.inSampleSize = 3;
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        }
    }
```

Calculation - InSampleSize

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Screenshot attached.[image]

Comment: did you check whether you got full image by means of bytes while downloading from URL

Comment: and did you compare the downloaded image bytes with url image content length

Comment: try something else,  Instead of decodeFile decodeStream BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ctx.openInputStream(uri), null, o);

Comment: if this method doesn't work you could try using the Picasso Library. This library is used to load pictures from url

Comment: @GauravArora Can you please, add more details on the conditions you are using? How many bytes are the images, and what is the device you are using? As far as I could read, your problem seems to be memory related. [Please, check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc) about using the System.gc().

Comment: @GauravArora Is this a JPG image? What version of Android? Is this reproducible in all devices? Also, have you found a fix for this?