# Why android does not clean up memory after finishing activity?

Tags: java, android, memory-management, android-memory, android-glide

In my case I have tow activities called A(Main Activity) and B (Child Activity).
A will start B (B having some image loading stuff using Glide image  library).

If I get the memory allocation using android memory monitor, I can clearly see the memory allocation grows.That is totally fine because we are doing some Image related things in activity B.Image Attached.

[image]

So my problem is if I pressed back button in Activity B it will come to activity A and allocated memory will not be cleared.Memory allocation will still in same amount.

**Is this normal android behaviour ?**

**If not how can I manually clean up memory ?**

I manually run GC as follows but same result no luck :(.

In activity B

```
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       System.gc();
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, GC will run only and only when really really needed (no more space of heap) and that's okay. Otherwise make sure absolutely nothing is referencing that memory (check for static references) and make sure you cleaned up some Android specific recources.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

**1)** `OnDestroy` is called when `finish();` is called, simply pressing back button won't call this method, unless you program it to do so.

**2)** `System.gc();` in onDestroy won't work, since your `activity B` is still active at `onDestroy`. You should call this from other Activity once the `activity B` is completely terminated.

**3)** Activity will remain on memory even `onDestroy` is called, if you leak your activities context to long lived object/thread/etc. (Memory leak)

**Note:** calling `System.gc();` does not simply free your memory, it might not execute GC depending on the situation. See details here: [Why is it bad practice to call System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc)