# How to add tinder card animation in view pager

Tags: android

I am currently struggling with giving tinder card animation effect in my view pager.
I am new to animation and dont know much about it.
I am currently using :AndTinder library.
here is my view pager code.

```
    import  android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
    import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
    import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;

    public class ItemPagerFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private CursorPagerAdapter adapter;
    private ImageButton favButton;
    private ImageButton shareButton;
    public ItemPagerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.gc();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_pager, container, false);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter in app.
        mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(-5, null, this);
        mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
        adapter = new CursorPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), null);
        mPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            //"Selected page position: " + ++position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                // Code goes here
            }

            // Called when the scroll state changes: 
            // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                // Code goes here
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        System.gc();
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), 
                DataProvider.CONTENT_URI_DATA, 
                null, 
                null, //            "favorite = 0" 
                null, 
                "RANDOM()");

        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        adapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

        adapter.swapCursor(null);
    }


    /**
     * A simple pager adapter.
     */
    private class CursorPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        //HashMap<Integer,ItemDetailFragment> hash = new HashMap<Integer,ItemDetailFragment>();
        ItemDetailFragment[] record = new ItemDetailFragment[3];
        //HashMap<Integer,ItemDetailFragment> hash = new HashMap<Integer,ItemDetailFragment>(3);

        private Cursor mCursor;


        public CursorPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Cursor c) {
            super(fm);
            mCursor = c;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                arguments.putLong(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DataProvider.COL_ID)));
                ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
               // System.out.println("putting page " + position + " in " + position % 3);
                record[position%3] = fragment;
                //hash.put(position , fragment);
                return fragment;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            if (mCursor != null) {
                return mCursor.getCount();
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            mCursor = cursor;
            try {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("exception caught");
            }

        }

        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){
            record[position%3] = null;
            super.destroyItem(container,position,object);

        }

        private ItemDetailFragment getfragment(int position)
        {
            return record[position%3];
            //return hash.get(position);
        }


        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            ItemDetailFragment f = (ItemDetailFragment ) object;


            int position = mPager.getCurrentItem();
            ItemDetailFragment current = adapter.getfragment(position);
            if(current.equals(f))
            {
                int fav = Integer.parseInt(f.data.getFavorite());
                if(fav == 1)
                    f.update(1);
                else
                    f.update(0);
            }
            return super.getItemPosition(object);


        }

        //changes to be done here
        /*public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

           ItemDetailFragment f = (ItemDetailFragment ) object;


            int position = mPager.getCurrentItem();
            System.out.println("prerna update "+position);
            ItemDetailFragment current = adapter.getfragment(position);
            if(current.equals(f))
            {
                System.out.println("prerna got it");
                int fav = Integer.parseInt(f.data.getFavorite());
                if(fav == 1)
                    f.update(1);
                else
                    f.update(0);
            }
            return super.getItemPosition(object);
              // return POSITION_NONE;//comment afterwards
            }*/

   }

}
```

can anybody please help me to do this.

Comment: Why `System.gc();` took place every where ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc

Comment: The code was taking to much memory space.