# is really image view set null ?

Tags: android

My problem is when i remove images from image View it remove image but when i monitor memory from android studio motorize tool it increasing memory 
**i am using Garbage collector .but its not good practice .**

help me out with different solution.

```
    private void cleanImages() {
        img1.setImageDrawable(null);
      }

 public void clickClean4(View view) {
        cleanImages();
        System.runFinalization();
        System.gc();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }
```

Comment: Calling `System.gc();` is ineffective. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc) and [this](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html)

Comment: You only have to use imageView.setImageDrawable(null)

Comment: Bob.when i use   imageView.setImageDrawable(null)  only so it not release memory

Answer (score 0):

You need to not only `setImageDrawable(null);` , but also recycle the bitmap.

You can do this by

```
 if (!bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().isRecycled()) {
        bitmapDrawable.getBitmap().recycle();
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank zaffy ..i use it before ,it is removing  image not release memory ..my issue is to release occupied memory