# How to remove and destroy labels from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx

I'm creating a chatting application in javafx. I'm displaying messages using labels and adding them in arraylist. Now i want to remove labels what should i do so that labels will be destroyed from scrollpane.

Here is code:

```
CONNECTION clientConnection=null;

@FXML ScrollPane chatScrollPane;
VBox chatVBox;
@FXML AnchorPane chatAnchorPane;


private List<Label> messages = new ArrayList<>();

int index = 0;
```

I'm adding messages like:

```
messages.add(new Label(m));
```

Should i assign new memory to messages so that garbage collector will remove labels from it?

eg?

```
 public void clearall(){
    /*for(int i=0;i<index;i++){

    }*/
    messages = null;
    System.gc();


    messages = new ArrayList<>();

    index = 0;

    System.out.println("cleared chat");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

List has a [`clear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#clear--) method, which will clear it.

Don't call `System.gc()`, that is [almost never needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc).

You don't show how you actually display the labels and how they actually get into the scroll pane, so I don't know if clearing the array list will actually clear the messages from the UI.  If you have further questions or issues, provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).