# Unusual memory consumption in working with fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-management, out-of-memory

I have a method in my program which I create a new fragment and start that fragment in it.
But we have several Out Of Memory crashes in our app, So I decided to look at the memory profiler of the android studio and this is the result of opening several fragments with this piece of code:
[image: memory usage after opening several fragments]

```
public void openFragment(MyCustomFragment fragment, boolean isDialog,
                         FragmentAnimationType animationType) {
    mStackCountAfterExternalIntent++;
    FragmentManager childFragmentManager = mFragmentAdapter.getItem(mActiveTab)
            .getChildFragmentManager();
    try {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if (animationType != null) {
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(animationType.enterAnimation, 0,
                        0, animationType.exitAnimation);
            }
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.child_fragment_root, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            if (childFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = mFragmentAdapter.getItem(mActiveTab)
                        .getChildFragmentManager();
                MyCustomFragment fragmentToHide = (MyCustomFragment) fragmentManager.
                        getFragments().get(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
            }
        System.gc();
        fragment.onVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        App.getInstance().restartApp(mLastIntent, false);
    }
}
```

I think this memory usage is unusual, Why the memory usage never goes down after opening a new fragment? Is this a result of memory leak? Do you have any suggestion for more investigating?

**Update1:**

MyCustomFragment is a fragment which extends from Android DialogFragment and also is a base for another fragments in my project, all of my fragments extends from it.

**Update2:**

I changed my fragments to extends from Fragment instead of MyCustomFragment and problem does not solved.

**Note1:**

what is mFragmentAdapter?: We have a bottom menu in project and use ViewPager and FragmentPagerAdapter for handling it and its tabs, this variable used for that.

Comment: May be we need to look into `MyCustomFragment`

Comment: [System.gc() isn't good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc)

Comment: Are you storing any fields in MyCustomFragment which have a context, for example any Views? they could be preventing MyCustomFragment from being GC'd

Comment: @FaizanMubasher It is just a customized and general fragment that extends from DialogFragment which another fragments in my project extend from it.Actually all of my fragments in my app extend from it. Need it?

Comment: What is the purpose of that (looks pretty bad) `if (childFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = mFragmentAdapter.getItem(mActiveTab)
                        .getChildFragmentManager();
                MyCustomFragment fragmentToHide = (MyCustomFragment) fragmentManager.
                        getFragments().get(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
            }
            System.gc();
            fragment.onVisible(true);` ?

Comment: @2Dee Yes, it was just for test, I will remove that line, Thank u for ur attention :)

Comment: @Peter Yes, there are some Fields with Type of "View", Actually they are some custom views, they cause this problem?

Comment: try to instantiate standard fragments and see if this happens. If it doesn't, post your custom fragments, custom views, everything you have

Comment: Yeah it seems that you have either messed up the backstack or more likely the fragment is holding a reference of himself (directly or via another object) and can't be garbage collected

Comment: I am really interested in seeing your implementation of mFragmentAdapter.

Comment: @HamidrezaSahraei it's a possibility and it's easy to check - just remove all the fields from your fragment and access everything with getView().findViewById() directly and see if that solves your leak. All views have Context which makes it a possibility for a leak. There are some additional common pitfalls here http://blog.nimbledroid.com/2016/05/23/memory-leaks.html

Comment: @MarkoPacak I tried your suggestion, but nothing changed, I have updated the question.

Comment: @HamidrezaSahraei I kind of ignored messed up backstack thing. If your implementation carelessly returns new fragment with every call to FragmentAdater#getItem, that could explain memory leaks. Also... why are you extending DialogFragment? It does not look for me like a good mix, I mean using DialogFragments + FragmentAdapter...

Comment: @Eselfar No it doesn't have any reference to itself, but would you explain about how backstack might be messed up?

Comment: @pablo432 Fragment adapter is for handling bottom menu which keep standard fragments in itself, MyCustomFragment is a dialog fragment for showing fragment as dialog in tablets and normal in phones.

Comment: What I meant was: instantiate plain fragments with your method and see if the error occurs again

Comment: I thought you where doing strange thing with the Fragments in the backstack but it seems ok. Can you please post your FragmentAdapter?

Comment: Same as @Eselfar, I'd look the problem inside the adapter.

Comment: How do you pass fragments to `openFragment`? Post that code as well