# Sockets of HttpURLConnection are leaked

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, connection-leaks

I'm using OpenJDK 11 on Linux and I need to make sure all my web requests done with HttpURLConnection are properly closed and do not keep any file descriptors open.

[Oracle's manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html) tells to use `close` on the `InputStream` and [Android's manual](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) tells to use `disconnect` on the `HttpURLConnection` object.

I also set `Connection: close` and `http.keepAlive` to `false` to avoid pooling of connections.

This seems to work with plain **http** requests but not encrypted **https** requests whose response is sent with **non-chunked encoding**. Only a GC seems to clean up the closed connections.

This example code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Test {
    private static int printFds() throws IOException {
        int cnt = 0;
        try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.list(new File("/proc/self/fd").toPath())) {
            for (Path path : (Iterable<Path>)paths::iterator) {
                System.out.println(path);
                ++cnt;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        return cnt;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // Must be a https endpoint returning non-chunked response
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://www.google.com/").openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while (in.readLine() != null) {
            }
            in.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            conn = null;
            in = null;
        }

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        int numBeforeGc = printFds();

        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        int numAfterGc = printFds();
        System.out.println(numBeforeGc == numAfterGc ? "No socket leaks" : "Sockets were leaked");
    }
}
```

prints this output:

```
/proc/self/fd/0
/proc/self/fd/1
/proc/self/fd/2
/proc/self/fd/3
/proc/self/fd/4
/proc/self/fd/5
/proc/self/fd/9
/proc/self/fd/6
/proc/self/fd/7
/proc/self/fd/8
/proc/self/fd/10
/proc/self/fd/11
/proc/self/fd/12
/proc/self/fd/13
/proc/self/fd/14
/proc/self/fd/15
/proc/self/fd/16
/proc/self/fd/17
/proc/self/fd/18
/proc/self/fd/19

/proc/self/fd/0
/proc/self/fd/1
/proc/self/fd/2
/proc/self/fd/3
/proc/self/fd/4
/proc/self/fd/5
/proc/self/fd/9
/proc/self/fd/6
/proc/self/fd/7
/proc/self/fd/8

Sockets were leaked
```

Changing to a http URL makes the sockets close correctly as expected without GC:

```
/proc/self/fd/0
/proc/self/fd/1
/proc/self/fd/2
/proc/self/fd/3
/proc/self/fd/4
/proc/self/fd/5
/proc/self/fd/6

/proc/self/fd/0
/proc/self/fd/1
/proc/self/fd/2
/proc/self/fd/3
/proc/self/fd/4
/proc/self/fd/5
/proc/self/fd/6

No socket leak
```

Tested with both OpenJDK 11 and 12. Did I miss something or is this a bug?

Comment: `System#gc` has no obligation to perform a garbage collection; it only serves as a hint for the GC to use. See: [Why is it bad practice to call System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc)

Comment: @Jacob G. The explicit `System.gc()` is just to illustrate the issue to show that it's the GC that cleans the sockets and not my `close()` and `disconnect()` calls.

Comment: maybe it's not closing because it's waiting for a response from the other side. (though it wouldn't explain the GC). Try doing a ~5 minutes sleep, perhaps 1 second isn't enough.

Comment: With netstat I see CLOSE_WAIT, so the other side has sent FIN.

Comment: I tried 5 minute sleep and there was no difference. By running strace, I see `shutdown(fd, SHUT_RD)`, but no `close` (until GC).

Comment: interesting! how about you try first disconnect and then close?

Comment: @Tomer that gives the same result.

Comment: BTW: are you omitting URLConnection.connect() on purpose? (checked the API and it should be called). In addition, try closing the output stream as well. The API states: "Invoking the close() methods on the InputStream or OutputStream of an URLConnection after a request may free network resources associated with this instance, unless particular protocol specifications specify different behaviours for it."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197748/discussion-between-tomer-and-emil).

Comment: The `connect()` call is not present in Oracle's and Android's examples. However I tried adding it before `getInputStream()` but didn't make any difference.

Comment: Interestingly, it isn’t just the socket.  The HttpURLConnection itself is not being garbage collected.

Comment: @Tomer Keep reading. It is called automatically when you get an input or output or error stream. And disconnect before close makes no sense.

Comment: Can you try a longer sleep? You seem to be still getting connection pooling at your end, although I would have expected a lot of connection reuse rather than new connections. I can't look it up now but is there an `https.keepAlive` system property?

Comment: I don't think it pools the connections since strace tells that it calls shutdown immediately when the input stream has been read to its end. I think openjdk just forgets to also call close. I also tried setting https.keepAlive to false but no difference.

Comment: I don't know why it calls shutdown. There is no shutdown in either HTTP or TLS, and in any case shutting down the input of a socket that is already at end of stream is totally redundant. Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: TLS 1.3 allows half-closed connections, so shutdown is valid for generic TLS streams, but I don't know why you would do it for HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be a bug after all: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8216326

`shutdownInput` is now replaced by `close` in the latest builds of JDK 11 and 13 (but not 12).