# Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space occurs in recursion

Tags: java, recursion, heap-memory

I'm using IntelliJ as an editor.
These are my vmoptions:

```
-Xms1024m

-Xmx4096m

-XX:MaxPermSize=700m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m

-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
```

Is there anything else I can change in the settings to make it work for me?

My algorithm tries to calculate the Matrix Chain Multiplication Problem via Branch&Bound and in this part(code below) I'm performing deapth-search/creating successors etc. I assume this recursion triggers the heap problem.

```
 public  static  SimpleMCPNode createTree(SimpleMCPNode currentNode) {
//other statements 
.
.
.
.
for (int i = 0; i < currentNode.matrices.size() - 1; i++) {
        List<MatrixInfo> adaptedList = new ArrayList(currentNode.matrices);
        currentNode.successors.add(createTree(currentNode.createSuccessor(adaptedList, i)));
    }
//other statements
.
.
```

Depending on the input it can grow exponentially...

Comment: What is the error that you are seeing ?

Comment: *"it can grow exponentially"* And you're confused it might run out of memory?

Comment: "Depending on the input it can grow exponentially...", if it does grow exponentially you could be simply running out of memory. There's not more than you can do then besides get a better algorithm or get more memory.

Comment: you are creating  a new ArrayList for each iteration. you should create the arraylist outside the loop

Comment: thank you guys, I will try to initialize it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to initialize a new arraylist each time.

Please use :

```
ArrayList<MatrixInfo> adaptedList = new ArrayList<MatrixInfo>();
for(int i=0; i< 10; i++){
  currentNode.successors.add(createTree(currentNode.createSuccessor(adaptedList,i)));
  adaptedList.clear() 
}
```

Comment: [Calling `gc()` is not a very good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105/why-is-it-bad-practice-to-call-system-gc), and it does not guarantee that the garbage collector is invoked.

Comment: the adaptedList must have the type <MatrixInfo> and I need for each node an own list of the matrices. Therefore, I don't know how to initiliaze it outside the loop

Comment: Then use adaptedList.clear() at the end of the each iteration

Comment: @kantarovski as you did above? I'm not sure If it helps, but I will try. Thanks mate