# Java Force Garbage collection without using JVMTI?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvmti

The only way I know to force garbage collection is to use [ForceGarbageCollection()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#ForceGarbageCollection) from JVMTI. Is there any cross-platofrm way to **force** GC (so I don't need to create a JVMTI library for each platform)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the answer is No.

But I also think that you shouldn't need to do this anyway.

The way to *request* the garbage collector to run is to call `System.gc()`.  But as the javadoc explains, this can be ignored.

The *normal* reason that `System.gc()` is ignored is that the JVM has been launched with the option `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC`.  This is NOT the default.  It only happens if the person or script or whatever launching the JVM *wants* this behavior.

So you are really asking for a way for an application override the user or administrator's explicit instructions to ignore `System.gc()` calls.  You should not be doing that.  It is not the application or the application writer's prerogative to override the user's wishes.

If your Java application *really* needs to run the GC explicitly, include in the installation instructions that it should NOT be run with the `-XX:+DisableExplicitGC` option.  Then `System.gc()` *should* work.

---

So why did they provide a way to disable `gc()` calls?

Basically because explicitly running the `gc()` is bad practice (see [Why is it bad practice to call System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105)) and (nearly always<sup>1</sup>) unnecessary in a properly written application<sup>2</sup>.  If you application relies on the GC running at specific times to function, then you have made a mistake in the application design.

<sup>1 - A couple of exceptions are *test cases* for code that uses `Reference` types and similar, and interactive games where you want to (say) clean up between levels to avoid a GC pause during normal play.

2 - It is not uncommon for a Java programmer to start out as a C or C++ programmer.  It can be difficult for such people to realize that they *don't need to* take a hand in Java memory management.  The JVM (nearly always) has better understanding of when to run the GC.  People also come across `Object.finalize` and dream up "interesting" ways to use it ... without realizing that it is an expensive and (ultimately) unreliable mechanism.</sup>