# How to force a Java-process to perform GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

While watching a Java-process with `jconsole`, I saw its heap-usage fluctuate between under 1Gb and above 3Gb. The same figures were output by the process itself -- we have GC-logging enabled.

On a whim I pressed the "Perform GC" button in `jconsole`, and the effect was quite dramatic -- the heap-usage fell under 1Gb *and stayed there*. It was still fluctuating, as might be expected, but never to the heights seen before.

[image: the red arrow points at when I forced garbage-collection]

This is Java-11 on Linux. Are there, perhaps, some JVM options to achieve more aggressive garbage-collection without a manual intervention? We have the CPU -- this app is mostly I/O bound anyway -- but we could use the 2Gb better than to store *garbage*...

Update, no, this is not a duplicate of [the earlier question](/questions/30458195/):

- I'm not asking *why* here, I'm asking for practical tips on *what to do*.
- The JVM is much newer -- 7 years, and G1 is now the default GC, unlike back then.

Comment: You can always cap the heap smaller.

Comment: the more full gc events, the lesser the application throughput. There is always a tradeoff. Reduce the heap and the GC events will increase. Whether these are full GCs or not depends on a variety of factors and there are different for different algorithms and JVM versions.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, we had the heap at 1Gb initially -- it would get busted _once in a while_, when the demand for memory spikes. So we increased it to 4Gb and now we see it _always_ hovering around 3Gb instead of only, when there is actual demand. This seems to be G1's standard behavior -- either we need to tweak it out of it, or change to ParallelGC, I guess... Hence, this question...

Answer (score 3):

> How to force a Java-process to perform GC?

It can trigger a full garbage collection by calling `System.gc()`.  Or you can do this externally; e.g. with `jconsole` or (I think) `jcmd`.

Caveats:

1. Depending on JVM's command line options a call to `System.gc()` may be ignored; i.e. it may do nothing.
2. Calling `System.gc()` on a regular basis is a bad idea.  It is bad for performance, because a full GC is expensive (compared to a new generation  collection) and because running the GC when there isn't a lot of garbage does a lot of work for little benefit.

   See [Why is it bad practice to call System.gc()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414105)

---

The interesting issue is why triggering a GC had that (on the face of it) beneficial effect.  There is not enough evidence to be sure, but I suspect that your JVM's heap had probably expanded to deal with a previous event where it has a very large working set.  Those object were presumably garbage collected, but the JVM was left with an oversized heap.

The JVM will downsize the heap when it detects that it is too large.  However that determination is only made following a full GC.  Presumably, since what was happening before you hit the button was that the JVM was only doing new space collections ... because the fast majority of new objects were "dying young".  That meant that the heap stayed large.

If the above hypothesis is correct, there is a related issue.  What if the heap actually needs to be that large in the long term?  What if you get *another* event where the GC needs a very large working set?  Answer, it will need to grow the heap again.  And that will entail at least one full GC and possibly more ... to get it to the required size.

What to do?

- Some Java GCs allow you to tune the heap resizing parameters.
- Some Java GCs allow you to run the GC periodically ... and make the periodic GC a full GC.
- Some Java GCs are designed to be less inclined to "hog" memory.

I would recommend using those rather than calling `System.gc()` ... and hoping.

Or maybe the best thing to do would be to leave it alone.

Question: Imagine if you squeeze the JVM's heap usage and then use the RAM you reclaimed for other things. Then another batch comes on requiring a (temporarily) large heap again.  What happens?

Answer: bad things!  Your Java heap expands to accommodate the larger working set, the system runs short of RAM and starts stealing pages from other processes, the system thrashing, and the OOM killer starts killing process.

---

Probably the most up to date resource on GC tuning is:

- [HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide for Java 17.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/gctuning/)

Comment: Yes, I saw the process' total size in `top` shrink from 4.6Gb to 1.7Gb. Should I try tweaking the G1, or simply switch to the Paralllel GC for this application entirely?

Comment: There are many factors in deciding your best choice of GC.  Process size in this edge case is just one factor.  My advise is to consider *all* factors that matter to you.  (Or just leave it alone.)